# A way to registrer Excel assemblies into the GAC

Tags: excel, ms-office, gac

I have developped a web application by using the ASP .NET MVC 3 framework.
I use programmatically Excel assemblies to create Excel workbooks.

My web application works fine on my development machine but it does not on the production machine.
Microsoft Office 2007 including MS Excel 2007 is installed on my development machine.
Therefore Excel assemblies are registred in the GAC.
But no version of MS Office is installed on the production machine.

I wonder if there is a way to register Excel assemblies into the GAC of the production machine other than installing MS Excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 issues here -

1. Installing the interop assemblies alone will not help you. The interop is merely an intermediary to excel. You must have excel installed to make use of excel functionality.
2. [Microsoft does not recommend or support using excel on the server.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757)

So - I would instead suggest that you use the [Office Open XML SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124) to generate the excel sheets that you need.